# Rails - Ransack - Custom attribute_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm using the `ransack` gem with my Rails application for an advanced search. How can I filter the `attribute_select` method to not show certain fields such as `id` and `created_at`, etc.

```
= f.attribute_fields do |a|
  = a.attribute_select
```

My current method above simply lists any and all attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Why your Ruby class macros (might) suck (mine did)](http://erniemiller.org/2012/05/11/why-your-ruby-class-macros-might-suck-mine-did/):

```
def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
  super - ['id', 'created_at']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the searchable attributes versus specifying the non-searchable ones like so:

```
def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    %w( searchable_attribute_goes_here another_one_goes_here ... ) + _ransackers.keys
end
```